# How to find Skype call failures via SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, skype, skype-for-business

I'm trying to build some reports on Skype for Business in SSRS. Most of it is fairly straight forward, looking at the SessionDetails table in LcsCDR.

Where I am struggling is in trying to find the data behind any failed calls. The outstanding requirement is to find dial time - how long the phone is ringing - for both answered calls and unanswered calls.

SessionDetails seems to only hold data on answered calls. Where would I find details on the failed calls?

Comment: please show some sample data and expected results

Comment: Do you know for a fact that this data is available? I would think it wouldn't start collecting data until a connection has been established. I looked a here (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398570.aspx) and I didn't see anything of what you are looking for.